# Add values that have same id in a text file

Tags: windows, file, file-manipulation

I'd like to know if there is a Windows command that enables to add two different values that have the same id in a file.

For example:

File :

```
id;value
01;25
02;12
01;2
03;21
03;-5
```

Result :

```
id;value
01;27 /* 25 + 2 */
02;12
03;16 /* 21 - 5 */
```

Answer (score 0):

For those who need the answer, I found a way to do it:

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
echo off

rem write header in output file
echo id;value> output.csv

rem remove the header of the file and loop
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=;" %%A in ('more +1 my_file.csv') do (
    set "result="

    rem search if current id is in the temp list (tmp file) of processed ids
    for /f "delims=" %%i in ('findstr /c:"%%A;" output.csv') do set result=!result!%%i

    rem if the id is not in tmp file (the id is not yet processed)
    if "!result!"=="" (
        set sum=0
        rem get all values related to the current id and calculate the sum 
        for /f "tokens=2 delims=;" %%V in ('findstr /c:"%%A;" my_file.csv') do (
            set /a sum+=%%V
        )
        echo %%A;!sum!>> output.csv
    )
)
```